# Web Application deployed in IIS is unable to access Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis

I have a web application developed in .net and deployed in IIS so that other systems on the LAN can access the application easily. It was all working fine but suddenly when i did some modification in application deployment services under world wide web under IIS in windows features on/off then my application unable to access database. I have checked everything i am able to access the same database in SQL server management studio.

Please help me

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: Check your connectionString

Comment: i have checked my connection string and it's ok

Comment: i am not getting any error, i have login page when i enter username password it redirect me to the same page without any error though it should redirect to the child page

Comment: Is your DB on the same machine as you application? Or is it on a remote server?

Comment: yes it is in the same machine in D dirve

Comment: Can you try to format your connection string like this: `Data Source=127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD`

Comment: my connection string is "<add name="con" connectionString="Data Source=ANKIT;Initial Catalog=DBSHOP;Integrated Security=True"/>"

Comment: nothing is happening.... :(

Comment: is there any way to check error is in which particular portion? actually it is hosted in iis right now and shared in LAN so how to check error

Comment: You can debug and check what is going wrong. Alternatively you could also add log to your application

Comment: In iis manager i checked the permission for my website i have given permission to iusr, iis_iusr, everyone to read and write but still nothing happening

Comment: You have not specified user Id and Password in your connection string?

Comment: no but it was working fine before

Comment: Can you try to add it and check. Also try to add log to your login function, so that you can be sure of what's wrong

Comment: "Also try to add log to your login function, so that you can be sure of what's wrong" how to add log that's what i needed to check actually what is the problem

Comment: I have just checked SQL server agent is stopped in sql server configuration manager is this creating problem?

Comment: There are various ways to add logs. You could use any 3rd party .NET Logging Libraries. One I have used is nLog. You could also output error to the page by using Response.Write(ex.message);

Comment: Thanks Arti, I have resolved my problem and it was very silly actually the problem with in the iis application pool i have stopped the pool and then started and the problem solved....!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem and it was very silly actually the problem with in the iis application pool i have stopped the application pool of my application and then started and the problem solved....!!!!